# Why am I not getting an error when are two objects having the name `out`?

Tags: java

I have written a small piece of code:

```
 System out = null;
 out.out.println("Hello");
```

This is working fine and is printing *"Hello"* on the console.

Now in my program or my scope, there are two objects having the name `out`. One is the object of `System` and another is the object of `PrintStream`.

Why am I not getting a compiler error/ runtime error that says `Duplicate local variable out.`?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where's the code that declares the second `out` you reference in your description?

Comment: Secound out is object of PrintStream which we use in Syso.

Comment: That doesn't make it a local variable…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's just one object named `out`, the `System`-type local variable. The other is named `out.out`, it is not directly "in your scope".

There is no reason for this to cause a compile-time error.

(BTW, calling static methods/referencing static fields via `null` references isn't really good practice, it's pretty confusing.)

Comment: Thanks Mat.I wanted to clear my basics.Thats why i asked this question.I dont know why somebody voted me down.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring two variables with same name in same scope. `out` that you declared is in your program's scope and PrintWriter's `out` is declared in System class as a static variable.

For example..

```
class System {
  ....
  PrintWriter out ;
  ....
}

class YourClass{
  public void yourMethod()
  {
     System out = null;
     // as PrintWriter's out is declared as static, so you can call like this
     // without any run-time exception such as NullPointerException
     out.out.println("Hello"); 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple: you are accessing a static field of class `System` in a legal, but frowned-upon manner: by qualifying it with a variable of type `System` instead of using literally the class name `System`. These two expressions have exactly the same meaning:

```
((System)null).out.println("a");
System.out.println("a");
```